# Error in serializing dictionary in Nancy

Tags: nancy

I have a route that returns a Dictionary like this:

```
public class HomeModule : NancyModule
{
    public HomeModule()
    {
        Get["/"] = _ => new Dictionary<long, long> {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
    }
}
```

When I call it I got a response with status 200 but with response body like so:

```
Unexpected 'E'
```

What is wrong?

Nancy version 1.4.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON keys have to be *string*, so the dictionary should be in this format:

```
public class HomeModule : NancyModule
{
    public HomeModule()
    {
        Get["/"] = _ => new Dictionary<string, long> {{"1", 2}, {"3", 4}};
                                    // ^
    }
}
```

And the result will be:

```
{
  "1": 2,
  "3": 4
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension for IResponseFormatter you could use in the module that would solve this issue for you.

```
this.Response.AsJson(new Dictionary<int,int>{{2,4}});
```